# Inherit from UserDict *and* dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance

I have a custom dict-like class which inherits from `UserDict`. It works perfectly, except that it is not an actual `dict`, i.e. `isinstance(my_userdict, dict)` returns `False`. This brings some problems with 3rd party code that makes the check (even `pprint` from stdlib behaves differently).

The obvious solution is to add `dict` to base classes.

```py
class MyFancyDict(UserDict, dict):
    ...
```

Am I not seeing some pitfall with this? Why doesn't `UserDict` already inherit from `dict`?

Comment: `collections.UserDict` is a legacy thing, created before inheritance from `dict` was even possible, and it was created specifically as a workaround for this old problem

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov well, I wouldn't say legacy exactly. It still serves a very useful purpose. Python built-in classes aren't very open to being extended. If you inherit from `dict`, methods that return an instance of the class will still return objects of the parent `dict` class, not the new subclass, unlike if you use `UserDict`. Probably `dict` is the least problematic of these.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov True, that is why it was created in the first place, but it doesn't mean it is legacy, because it solves other issues as well. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#userdict-objects) say that the need for UserDict has been "partially supplanted" but also that it "can be easier to work". And a quick google gives a ton of recent articles explaining pitfalls of extending dict directly.

Comment: @DarkKnight All true, but by adding dict to its bases, a UserDict can more effectively masquerade as a "real" dict (which is, arguably, its original purpose). My question is: are there any technical downsides of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in some cases - but not in all.

You have to be aware that are 2 kinds of code that demand  direct `dict` inheritance:(1) naive code which could just test for a generic mapping, but is stuck with an `isinstance(obj, dict)` inside; and (2) code in extensions which bypass the slots for magic methods, and instead hardcode the calls to Python's dict API. That is, instead of requesting the object's `__getitem__` method and going through that, the code is written in C and will call `PyDict_GetItem`  (and other PyDict* methods listed here - https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html ).

These C calls rely on the object being a direct dictionary, and on its data been placed in the correct place in the computer memory - None of them will work with a dictionary subclass that will redirect the storage (for example, UserDict uses an wrapped dictionary in the `.data` attribute). But most of them will work if you inherit `dict` and just add new functionality in other methods. (But not if you try to transform the dictionary data in `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`: your Python code will likely be bypassed).

So, if it works for pprint, one is in luck. It won't work in other cases (`json.dump`, for example, if the native code encoder is used)